# Why I can't see a $scope variable that was defined in a $scope function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope

I have the following piece of code in angular

```
$scope.prepare = function(){
   $scope.elems = [1,2,3];
};

$scope.action = function(){
   var elem = $scope.elems[0]; //undefined
}
```

then, in my view, I use the directive ng-init="prepare()" and attach to a button the **action** function on click event

```
<button ng-click="action()">action</button>
```

Inthe action function the scope hasn't the elems array defined?

Can anybody tell me why this happen?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you make an example replicating this?

Comment: Are you sure `prepare()` is getting called? My guess is it isn't. Perhaps if you can give us a fiddle that reproduces this we can help better.

Comment: Are those two codes in the same controller? if not, both `$scopes` will belong to different controllers

Comment: Instead of using `ng-init` (which is not recommended for most situations), manually invoke `$scope.prepare()` at the end of your controller definition.

Comment: Why even wrap `$scope.elems` in a function in the first place?

Comment: your code should work: see http://jsfiddle.net/seqvewe4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are not showing the controller or the scope of the HTML where you are calling init() and action(), I can't even guess why you are having problems since the code you have posted works. This is a pluker proving that much: http://plnkr.co/edit/qMzPtJtp9t9CoNKkmWIc?p=preview

```
<div ng-init="prepare()"></div>
<input type="button" value="Call function" data-ng-click="action()" />
<p>Init Defined: {{elems}}</p>
<p>Function call: {{redefined}}</p>


$scope.prepare = function(){
   $scope.elems = [1,2,3];
  };

  $scope.action = function(){
   $scope.redefined = $scope.elems[0]; //undefined
  }
```

With that said, you are not using ng-init() correctly. From the angluar documentation:

"This directive can be abused to add unnecessary amounts of logic into your templates. There are only a few appropriate uses of ngInit, such as for aliasing special properties of ngRepeat ... and for injecting data via server side scripting. Besides these few cases, you should use controllers rather than ngInit to initialize values on a scope."

Link to ng-init documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit

You will be much better off initializing your array in the controller.

Comment: The problem was that the button that trig the action was outside of scope of prepare. For this reason the action function was enabled to see the elms array